# Need component that switches on a higher voltage and current

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, voltage, transistors

I am developing an ATMEGA382 project meant to automate certain aquarium maintenance functions. I need to apply power to 12volt solenoids and pumps. I thought I would use an NPN transistor like a switch with a 3.3v base and 12v collector. I understand this is incorrect. I do not necessarily need high speed switching. What would be a better option? I looked at an IBGF transistor, but that seems to have the same issue I am already facing.

Should I just dump a bunch of 3.3v into both base and collector with a boost converter on the emitter?

Thanks!

Comment: MOSFETS would be better, or RELAYs if it's pretty low duty cycle and you need the isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Your description sounds like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFpRzp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this circuit the transistor is an emitter follower.  The emitter voltage will be 0.7 volts less than the base voltage.

You should instead do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF1yWA.png)</sup>

With this circuit the transistor will act as a switch, and will have about 0.2 volts between emitter and collector when the base is pulled up by the ATMega output.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at some sort of *isolated* component. Relays are mechanically isolated - your 3.3V would drive the coil and the switch would handle the 12V side. Optoisolators are the solid state version of a relay (in the crude sense) - they use a light signal generated by your 3.3V to drive an optically sensitive phototransistor. For this application with low switching frequency, I think a relay is going to be the way to go, but you will most likely need a transistor to interface your controller logic level with the relay coil current, which is in the 100mA range - take [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G5LE-14-DC5/Z1011-ND/280371) as an example.